# PyTorch: Broadcasting a weighted sum of tensors

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, tensor

I am wondering whether I could broadcast the operation below without using a for loop.

```
X1 = torch.rand(B,d)
X2 = torch.rand(B,d)
X3 = torch.rand(B,d)
X = [X1,X2,X3]
w = torch.rand(3)

res = 0
for i in range(3):
  res += X[i] * w[i]:
```

An important thing to note here is that **w is a parameter that I need to optimize**. So I need to track its gradient.

Any help would be appreciated.

I just don't know how to speed up this operation without ruining the gradient map.

Comment: Can you parallel process the multiplication of X1, X2, and X3, then calculate their sums? Naturally multithreading wouldn't work, but if X1, X2, and X3 are sufficiently small they can be held in memory and computed with a seperate process. Also, on a similar veign, I image addition can be multiprocessed by segmating the tensor, thought I'm not familiar with pytorch and I'm not confident that would preserve differentiability/gradients

Comment: note: reading between the lines here, if this is in some sort of train loop you'll probably want the processes which do calculation to persist between loops so you're not hit with process initialization times every iteration.